# Polynomial degree 3 Equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

**Question:**

> If $p(x) \in F[x]$ is of degree $3$, and $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$, show that $p(x)$ is irreducible over $F$ if there is no element $r\in F$ such that $a_0+a_1r+a_2r^2+a_3r^3 =0$.

**My understanding:**

If $p(x)$ is reducible, then there exists $ax + b$ such that $a, b \in F$ and $a\ne 0$. And $p(x) = (ax + b)(cx^2 + dx + e)$. Then an $r$ exists such that $p(r) = 0$.
Is that how you're supposed to tackle it?

I understand that I am supposed to first explain the argument for a polynomial of degree 1, but I do not understand how to go about that, and why that helps.

Comment: Yes, except you need to explain why a degree 1 polynomial must divide it, and also what $r$ is.

Comment: For thoroughness you could explain why you know there is an $r$ such that $p(r)=0$. True, it is obvious that you know why, but one might as well be explicit.

Comment: What is the most obvious way to explain that a polynomial of degree 1 will divide the equation - the fundamental thm of algebra?

Comment: First, if reducible, then the only way is $3=1+2$ or $3=1+1+1$ (and the latter can be transformed into former.) Second as you can see, $(ax+b)|p(x)$. Thus $r=-b/a$ is a solution to $p(x)=0$, since $p(r)=(ar+b)\cdot(\ldots)=0$ when $ar+b=0$, and done.

Comment: Suppose that there exists an element $\alpha \in F$ such that $p(\alpha) = 0$. Since F is a field, $F[x]$ is a Euclidean Domain and hence by the Division Algorithm, we must have $p(x) = (x - \alpha)q(x) + r(x)$. Why must $r$ be identically zero? Is $p(x)$ still irreducible then?

Comment: Notation $F$ makes it likely that you are dealing with a field here. If so then this should be mentioned in your question.

Comment: @akech, Because by counterexample r must be a nontrivial solution. It is reducible then.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your theorem says that, if no $r \in F$ such that $a_0 + a_1r + a_2r^2 + a_3r^3=0$ exists (the polynomial has no roots in $F$), then $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3$ is irreducible over $F$.

And after all, if that polynomial were reducible, you'd be able to write it as a product of two polynomials, none of which is a constant. So, according to your example, you could maybe write $p(x)$ as $(n_o + n_1x)(m_0 + m_1x + m_2x^2)$. But then, $r = -n_0/n_1 \in F$ would be a root of such polynomial, since it yields $0 \cdot (m_0 + m_1x + m_2x^2) = 0$, which goes against the fact that no $r$ with that property existed. This works also if you wrote the polynomial as a product of three other polynomials of degree $1$, that is the only other possibility left.

Answer (score 1):

You have what looks like a reasonable outline but I'm guessing you don't understand parts of it since you're asking this question.

> If $p(x)$ is reducible, then there exists $ax + b$ such that $a, b \in F$ and $a\ne 0$. And $p(x) = (ax + b)(cx^2 + dx + e)$.

Why?  (Note that this is only true for a cubic, not for anything of higher degree.  What's the difference?)

> Then an $r$ exists such that $p(r) = 0$.

Yes, but what, specifically, is $r$?

Comment: R is the solution, (x-r), for which p(r) is 0.

Comment: But you can tell me exactly what $r$ is, given the previous sentences.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @SamSmith He means if we have a zero of $(ax + b)$, what is it?  That is, what is the value of $x$ that makes the factor $(ax + b)$ equal to $0$?

Comment: Oh then r should be -b/a. It is contained within p(r), and since p(x) is within F[x] it is contained within F[x} too.

Comment: @SamSmith Well what do you mean when you say it is contained within $p(r)$?  What you should mean is that since $a$ and $b$ are coefficients of the polynomial $(ax + b)$ which is in $F[x]$, then $a, b \in F$.  But $F$ is a field, so the quotient of two elements is in it, too.  So $-\frac{b}{a}$ is in $F$, too.  But this contradicts the fact that our original polynomial doesn't have a root in $F$, since we found a factor of the original polynomial that *does* have a root in $F$.

Comment: -b/a also lives within F, by the logic that p(x) is contained in F[x] and r=-b/a is in p(x).

Comment: @SamSmith Again, I don't know what you mean by "$r = -\frac{b}{a}$ is in $p(x)$".  Here is how the proof works:  So we have a polynomial $p(x)$ such that there is *no* $r \in F$ with $p(r) = 0$.  We want to prove $p$ is irreducible in $F[x]$ (the polynomial ring with coefficients in the field $F$).  To prove $p$ is irreducible, suppose by contradiction that it is reducible.  Then we can find a linear factor in $p(x)$, namely, $ax + b$, so that $p(x) = (ax + b)(cx^{2} + dx + e)$, and both $(ax + b)$ and $(cx^{2} + dx + e)$ are in $F[x]$.  But, since $(ax + b)$ is in $F[x]$,...

Comment: @SamSmith ...that means $a \in F$ and $b \in F$, since a polynomial in $F[x]$ means the coefficients are in $F$. But $F$ is a field, so the element $-\frac{b}{a}$ is in $F$.  But $-\frac{b}{a}$ makes $(ax + b)$ equal to $0$.  And since it makes $(ax + b)$ equal to $0$, it makes $p(x) = (ax + b)(cx^{2} + dx + e)$ equal to $0$, so $-\frac{b}{a}$ is a zero of $p(x)$.  But it is impossible for us to have an element of $F$ as a root of $p(x)$ by our initial assumption.  So since we found a contradiction, it must be that $p(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$, as desired.  Does this make sense?